# Prevent the Gmail label list from automatically collapsing

Tags: gmail

In Gmail's new UI, is there a way to prevent the "label list", or whatever you call it, from automatically collapsing whenever I'm not hovering over it with mouse/trackpad? This is what I mean (here shown collapsed):

This is truly the most annoying thing and there is no way I can see to adjust the size or turn the function off. It just recently installed itself. The suggestions so far did not work or were not relevant to what I am seeing in my Gmail.

Comment: if you meant to add a picture, it got missed out

Answer (score 10):

Press the "hamburger" menu at the top left.  It is a toggle to expand/collapse the Gmail menu.  It is not the most intuitive setting.

[image: Gmail stop left sidebar from collapsing via hamburger menu]

Comment: The least intuitiv setting I ever came across. Thanks for solving this issue.

Comment: Oh, man! I was crying for a week until I decided to google this question, and finally, I'm happy. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have an extension conflicting with Gmail or a cache issue - the sidebar with all your labels should be staying open when your mouse isn't over it if you click "More". Try opening Gmail in an Incognito window or in another browser without extensions and see if that fixes the behavior.

When you click a label in the top list (Above the fold of the "More" Button) the list will collapse again, and there's not a built-in way in Gmail to modify this behavior.